# Magento 2 - How to remove catalog.leftnav only from category pages with 2columns-right.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

I have created a Magento 2 module which has some customization for the category pages.

I would like to remove catalog.leftnav when the category is using the "2 columns with right bar" layout. Is there anyway I can do this in my modules Layout files?

So far I've tried adding `<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />` to `<my_module_dir>/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-right.xml` but this did nothing.

Then I tried adding `<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />` to `<my_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` but this removed it from everywhere, even pages with 3 column layout.

**UPDATE**

After reading through the [docs on this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html), I have now also tried creating the following file
`app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/2columns-right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <body>
        <!--<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" before="-"/>-->
        <!--<update handle="2columns-right"/>-->
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
    </body>
</layout>
```

But this did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

catalog.leftnav is a container so you need to use:

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

When you are choosing the layout for the category, you can also remove the leftnav by updating the Layout Update XML settings for the category with this. It is right below the page layout option.